# Tensorflow TocoConverter gives toco_from_protos error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I basically used freeze_graph to freeze the model and then tried to use    TocoConverter to convert the model to tflite, however it gives me the error:

```
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'/bin/sh: 1: toco_from_protos: not found\n'
None
```

Below is my code:

```
graph_def_file = './frozen_model2.pb'
input_arrays = ['IteratorGetNext']
output_arrays = ['model/fc_result/prediction/BiasAdd']

converter = tf.contrib.lite.TocoConverter.from_frozen_graph(
graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi user10443246, I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The error `b'/bin/sh: 1: toco_from_protos: not found\n'` indicates that the shell command `toco_from_protos` is not found. I'm guessing `toco --help` doesn't work for you either.

I built Tensorflow 1.9.0 from source so I assume I must have screwed up a step where shell commands like `toco` and `toco_from_protos` get set up.

Anyway, my traceback was this:

```
  File "/home/casey/anaconda3/envs/mnist/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py", line 330, in convert
    dump_graphviz_video=self.dump_graphviz_video)
  File "/home/casey/anaconda3/envs/mnist/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py", line 263, in toco_convert
    input_data.SerializeToString())
  File "/home/casey/anaconda3/envs/mnist/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py", line 107, in toco_convert_protos
    (stdout, stderr))
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'/bin/sh: 1: toco_from_protos: not found\n'
None
```

If you follow the traceback to line 107 in `[python path]/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py`, you'll see there is some logic in the definition for `toco_convert_protos()` to run `toco_from_protos` as a shell command:

```
# TODO(aselle): When toco does not use fatal errors for failure, we can
# switch this on.
if not _toco_from_proto_bin:
    return _toco_python.TocoConvert(
        model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str)

with _tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fp_toco, \
           _tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fp_model, \
           _tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fp_input, \
           _tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fp_output:
    fp_model.write(model_flags_str)
    fp_toco.write(toco_flags_str)
    fp_input.write(input_data_str)
    fp_model.flush()
    fp_toco.flush()
    fp_input.flush()

    cmd = [
        _toco_from_proto_bin, fp_model.name, fp_toco.name, fp_input.name,
        fp_output.name
    ]
    cmdline = " ".join(cmd)
    proc = _subprocess.Popen(
        cmdline,
        shell=True,
        stdout=_subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=_subprocess.STDOUT,
        close_fds=True)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    exitcode = proc.returncode
    if exitcode == 0:
      stuff = fp_output.read()
      return stuff
    else:
      raise RuntimeError("TOCO failed see console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" %
                         (stdout, stderr))
```

If your `toco` and `toco_from_protos` shell commands aren't working then obviously this step will fail.

I made this change as a workaround in `[python path]/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py`, to force the first case to return:

```
  if _toco_from_proto_bin:
  # if not _toco_from_proto_bin: # comment out this line to force return
    return _toco_python.TocoConvert(
        model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str)
```

Janky, but it got the job done for me. The proper solution would probably be to reinstall a version of Tensorflow that has working `toco` or redo the bazel build if you are building from source.

Comment: It worked for me. Is there some downside of this fix?

Comment: @dankal444 glad it worked but this doesn't actually fix the root cause, which is your toco_from_protos shell command being set up incorrectly. This is just a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the toco scripts are in your search path. Check PATH variable.

It seems that they are installed in `/home/user/.local/bin` so add this to `PATH` variable.

Comment: Best way to confirm whether this is the issue is to enter `where toco` in the command line. If it lists multiple locations (or none), then you need to fix your path.

Comment: @Patrick do you mean if there are multiple locations for toco that there is also a problem? And how would do you fix your path if that is the case?

Comment: @IgorHoogerwoord I'm referring to your path variable (I'm using windows), or whatever the equivalent is on your OS

Comment: @Patrick yes understood that you're referring to the PATH variable. You mentioned that 'if it lists multiple ( or none )' then I need to fix the path. In my case it lists multiple paths, so does this mean there is a problem that I can fix?

Comment: @IgorHoogerwoord Well, yes. Isn't that exactly what I said in my first comment?

Comment: @Patrick yes, just wanted to clear up what the specific issue is, and hope to find out how to fix the path. 
It turns out there is an issue within Tensorflow that even after adding the virtualenv/bin directory to PATH where toco resides it still does not find it when running the program in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Download and build tensorflow from source
2. Use google collab if you don't want to install tensorflow from
   source [Here i made video on how to fix this Error](https://youtu.be/IJt_veyTlv8)

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this problem when quantizing a model into integer-precision.

```sh
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'/bin/sh: 1: toco_from_protos: not found\n'
```

The key is to find where does `toco_from_protos` actually reside.

I use `locate` command to search across ALL files in my Linux system. (newly installed Linux may need to call `updatedb` on the first time, to create an initial database).

```sh
bash   > locate toco_from

result > /usr/local/intelpython3/bin/toco_from_protos
```

Bingo, let see if there are more things in this folder

```sh
ls /usr/local/intelpython3/bin/toco*

/usr/local/intelpython3/bin/toco
/usr/local/intelpython3/bin/toco_from_protos
```

**My custom python installation requires manual configuration in order to be properly exposed to PATH**

So I added the following lines in my `~/.profile`

```sh
PYTHONBIN=/usr/local/intelpython3/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$PYTHONBIN
```

and I made it in effect immediately by:

```sh
source ~/.profile
```

Then everything goes well again.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try it on latest tensorflow (not tensorflow-gpu).
Worked for me